# Get id of last inserted row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP for server side scripting and mysql server for database.
If I use `mysql_insert_id()` then it gives "0" and use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` causes error "object returned empty description".This error I see when I debug on client-side in objective-C.
My table's id column is auto generated. I dont' pass id explicitly.

Below is the PHP code :

```
 // Connect to our database
    $db = Frapi_Database::getInstance();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userTrip 
        (userId, fromLat, fromLon, fromLoc, fromPOI,
        toLat, toLon, toLoc, toPOI,
        tripFinished, isMatched, departureTime, createdAt)
        values 
        (".$userId.",".$fromLat.",".$fromLon.", GeomFromText('POINT($fromLat $fromLon)')".",'".$fromPOI."',".$toLat.","
            .$toLon.", GeomFromText('POINT($toLat $toLon)')".",'".$toPOI."',0,0,'".
            $departureTime."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);        

    if (!$stmt->execute())
        throw new Frapi_Error('ERROR_INSERTING_RECORD');

    $lastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    $this->data['tripId'] = $lastId;
    $db = null;
```

Comment: did you try to check if your insertion is successfull?

Comment: Check that record inserted or you have auto incremented primary key because  mysql_insert_id()  returns 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Frapi Database](https://github.com/frapi/frapi/blob/master/src/frapi/library/Frapi/Database.php) extends from [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), so you would use this:

```
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

See also: [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: thanks @Jack. I used `$db->lastInsertId()`. It gives value. But this is not correct value. I use Frapi Database. Every time run `insert action`in tester, it gives new id by adding 4 to last one, whereas it should add 1. Another thing is that last id in my table is 138 and it gave 201.

Comment: @AkashPatel How do you know that value is wrong? Inserted id may not increase by exactly 1 all the time. Rolled back transactions and master-master replication setups could cause that.

Comment: It increases by 1 in table. I don't know about setups you said. I'll find the reason. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (if you use `mysqli`):

```
 $db->insert_id;
```

Or (if you use `PDO`):

```
 $db->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this ?

to get the last inserted id

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

it will work for you,try this link [mysql_insert_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-insert-id.html)
and [this](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysql-insert-id.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If your table  have  AUTO INCREMENT column like UserID,Emp_ID,.. then you can use this query to get last inserted record

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where UserID=(select MAX(UserID)from table_name)
```

In PHP code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'userid', 'password', 'database_name');
if (!$con) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name where UserID=(select MAX(UserID)from table_name)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

*Then you can use fetched data as your requirement*